# uploading data using esp32 to google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, sensors, esp32, anomaly-detection, real-time-updates

Is it possible to upload data directly from esp32 to google colab to achieve real-time anomaly detection? I don't want to go through google sheets because it will add delay to my system due to connection problems.

Comment: Colab is not really good for running a production system in. Recommend putting the model onto Heroku or similar.

Answer (score 1):

[MQTT](https://mqtt.org/) is a protocol suitable for communicating data from device and to the cloud. There are many libraries for the ESP32 that supports it.
Since MQTT uses a message broker, it allows multiple clients to get the same data. One client can be your model running interactively in Google Colab. Another client could be a data ingestion that stores the data into a database for archival.